# Android ListView Click On WebBrowser

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

I create a `ListView` and I added some information news with http link.

I want to open a web browser when I click one of the links in the listview

I added information into array1 and added link array2.

How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                newsarraylist);

new NewThread().execute();

}
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("İzmir Üniversitesi Haberleri");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
        // mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements table = doc.select("table.contentpane td:eq(1)");
            Elements links=doc.select("table.contentpane a[href]");
            for (Element tables : table) {
                newsarraylist.add(tables.text());
            }
            for (Element link : links) {
                newarraylistlink.add(link.html());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
private void registerClick(){
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            myweb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
            myweb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myweb.loadUrl(newarraylistlink.toString());

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Please be more verbose when asking questions, answer important questions an answerer may have, like "What is it you're seeing now?", "What is it you're expecting instead?". If my answer doesn't help, please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing the wrong URL to `WebView`, `newarraylistlink` is a `List`, so you will want to pass `newarraylistlink.get(position)` to `loadUrl`.